# get bounding rect of popup notification

Tags: windows, winapi, popup

I want to know the location and size of some popup notifications in Windows. like the notification that Windows Defender shows when you did not update it for a while(or many other apps/programs show usually on bottom right of the screen)

if the popup was a window, I would first get the handle to it and then use `GetWindowRect`. but i'm not even sure what popups are exactly. another approach would be image processing but for a lot of reasons i don't think it is a good approach. i tried it and because there are lots of different popups(even those a single software may produce) and because of things like different screen resolutions, different taskbar locations and messy backgrounds, it did not work so good.

**PS:** maybe they are [flyouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/flyouts)

Comment: Search for "UI automation"

Comment: @zett42 um ... i'm not sure how UI automation can help me. can you be more specific? also do you know what kind of object those things are?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: UIA helps you to get properties like position and size of almost all UI elements like windows, buttons, etc., independent from the GUI technology that is used. Windows SDK comes with "Inspect.exe" which you can use to get knowledge about a specific window, how to identify it and which UIA properties are available. [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). Specifically you need the [client API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/uiauto-clientportal).